# Floating Links Hover

Tags: html

I'm brand-new to html and decided to make a start page for Firefox. The problem I have is that when I mouseover above and below my links' text my mouse's cursor changes to the hotlink pointy hand, as it would normally when you mouseover a link. But it does this within a 20+ pixel radius above and below that link in an invisible field it would seem. It doesn't do this to the left and right of the link text. I want to fix it so that it only changes when my mouse is directly over the text, as all website links do. I'm probably missing some code. Here's my full html code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="author" content="name">
<title>~name@inferno</title>
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: url(x.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #0A0F14;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
td {
    transition: all 2s ease 0.9s;
    color: inherit;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
a:link {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}
td:hover{
    background: rgba(16, 21, 27, 0);
}
.box {
background: #10151B;
border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 10px;
line-height: 50px;
width: 140px;
height: 592px;
position: fixed;
top: 1px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
.icon {
color: #D12248;
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
text-indent: 5px;
}
.icon2 {
color: #D19011;
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
text-indent: 5px;
}
.icon3 {
color: #57A3D1;
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
text-indent: 5px;
}
.icon4 {
color: #AAD130;
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
text-indent: 5px;
}
.icon5 {
color: #4ED1B3;
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
text-indent: 5px;
}
.icon6 {
color: #98D1CE;
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
text-indent: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This code only contains the CSS definitions, can you also show the link that you mentioned?  what element is it? (<a>?)

Comment: Added a fiddle - jsfiddle.net/aw09geqh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your issue was the '`float:right`' in the CSS.
That made the a element take up all the space of the box.

Try setting a line height so that the 'a' element will be limited in height:

```
a {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;    //updated the margin top
  line-height: 15px;   //added line height
}
```

The line-height change makes it so the a appears in the top of the row.
Updating margin-top fixes that.

https://jsfiddle.net/aw09geqh/1/

Comment: Without float:right the text aligns to the left, which is not what I wanted, even with text-align: right.

Comment: @Lex Updated answer to use float

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it! ^.<

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this rule:

```
td:hover{
    background: rgba(16, 21, 27, 0);
}
```

It's hard to say without seeing the HTML, but from what you write, that might be it.

Comment: It's not the td:hover that's causing it.

Comment: it's due to the 50px line-height on .box, but there's no quick cure for that - you'll have to restructure the whole thing a bit...